# In my discord bot ctx.author.voice.channel is not returning any value

Tags: discord, discord.py

I want my discord bot to send me a message if there is no one in a voice channel.

```
async def play(self, ctx, *args):
        query = " ".join(args)
        voice_channel = ctx.author.voice.channel
        print(voice_channel)
        if voice_channel is None:
            print('test')
            #you need to be connected so that the bot knows where to go
            # await message.channel.send(response) 
            await ctx.send("Connect to a voice channel!")
        elif self.is_paused:
            print('poop')
            self.vc.resume()
        else:
            print('hello')
            song = self.search_yt(query)
            if type(song) == type(True):
                await ctx.send("Could not download the song. Incorrect format try another keyword. This could be due to playlist or a livestream format.")
            else:
                await ctx.send("Song added to the queue")
                self.music_queue.append([song, voice_channel])
                
                if self.is_playing == False:
                    await self.play_music(ctx)
```

However, if I'm not in the voice channel, nothing gets returned. If I do `print(voice_channel)` literally nothing shows up in my linux terminal, not even a None value. Any thoughts here?

Answer (score 2):

Because if you are not in the voice channel, `ctx.author.voice` will be `None`. Then, `None.channel` will lead to an uncaught exception, which is `NoneType Object has no attribute`. 
To check whether command author is in the channel or not. Consider checking its `voice`, sth like

```py
voice = ctx.author.voice
if voice is None:  # author is not in the voice channel
  # do sth like telling author should join a voice channel and return
  return

# it means author joins a voice channel
print(voice.channel)  # to get the author's channel
```

Also, if you want to check whether the music is still playing or not. You need to access your bot `voice_client`, not the command author (which is the user)'s  `voice_client`. You could do sth like:

```py
bot_voice = ctx.voice_client  # shortcut to ctx.guild.voice_client
if bot_voice and bot_voice.is_paused():  # bot connects to a channel and music is paused
  bot_voice.resume()
elif ... :  # maybe check voice and do some connection stuff
```

Comment: THANK YOU! going to try this out... it makes perfect sense. i've never encountered an uncaught exception before. thank you!!! i'll let u know how it goes.

Comment: it works! i'm able to get to the next part of my code... it needs debugging... but thank you!

Comment: @RyanTom Yeah, and if you couldn't see any error printing to the terminal, consider using discord.py logging. [docs link](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/logging.html)